# Where are the four telescopes in Southern Shelf Bay?

Tags: borderlands-2

The "I Can See Your Corpse from Here!" challenge in Southern Shelf - Bay requires actioning four telescopes. I found one on the ship, one on the fort's top level, and one in-between the bridges, but it'd be good to show all four locations in greater detail. (There's also a telescope outside Liar's Berg, but I don't think it counts.)

[image: Four telescopes]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**They're all near the Bay's fort.**

1. **In-between the two bridges** en route to the fort, facing back whence you came
2. **Atop the fort** (the top level), looking over the water
3. Around the archipelago of scrap wood in the water, **close to but before the ship**, looking out over the water
4. **On the ship's upper level**, facing towards the fort

[image]

Comment: The spot on the map is incorrect for the 3rd one. It's on the boat to the left of it.

Answer (score 4):

I found this:

> I can see your corpse from here
>   You need to locate all the telescopes in the southern shelf bay. The first one is quite easy. You will find it inside the small camp as you rise up the hill after the ferry. The next two can be found on the boats in the town, and the last one will be found on that highest point in the town.

Read more: http://segmentnext.com/2012/09/17/borderlands-2-challenges-guide-how-to-complete/#ixzz26uSxWXAH

Answer (score -2):

I believe each telescope points to the next one.

Comment: The one between the bridges points away from the other three